# Using a configurable enumerator

Tags: c#, generics, compact-framework, enumeration

I have a class which encapsulates a collection of items we'll call `ItemCollection`. I need to expose two different enumerators for working with this collection: One simply enumerates all items (`Item`) and the second only enumerates those that are a specific derived type (`T where T:Item`). A wrinkle is that this part of some real time library code running on the compact framework and it really needs to avoid allocating objects on the heap that could trigger a collection in the middle of the foreach loop. I've been using struct Enumerators to fill that requirement.

```
public class ItemCollection
{
    public ItemEnumerator GetEnumerator() {}
    public ItemGenericEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator<T>() {} // Probably not correct
}

public struct ItemEnumerator : IEnumerator<Item>
{
    Item Current;
    bool MoveNext() {}
    void Reset() {}
}

public struct ItemGenericEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T> where T : Item
{
    T Current;
    bool MoveNext() {}
    void Reset() {}
}
```

On the face of it I don't see how to make a specific call to `GetEnumerator<T>` and indeed I started with this:

```
public class ItemCollection
{
    public ItemEnumerator GetEnumerator() {}
    public ItemGenericEnumerator<T> ItemsOfType<T>() {}
}

foreach(var item in collection.ItemsOfType<X>)
```

But I immediately ran into `does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`.

One solution is to have ItemsOfType return a generic throw away class with a constructor that receives the enumerator and a single GetEnumerator method  but that implementation breaks the no heap allocation requirement (would a throw away struct that returns another struct with GetEnumerator work?).

Another discarded option is to simply use the first enumerator and require the type to be checked manually, it's only one extra line of code. However the current implimentation details of ItemCollection mean there is a big difference between returning only items of one type compared to pulling all items and then sorting them outside the box.

Comment: What is the underlying storage container holding the `Item` or derived `T` items in your `ItemCollection` ?

Comment: A web of linked lists and unsafe code that mixes items from many collections together, designed to work close to a hardware API. ItemCollection is a way to bridge the gap between the safe and unsafe parts of the code. Implimentation wise it would be closer to say that items are internally group by type instead of collection which is why ItemsOfType is much faster (go directly to one group of typed items and then filter by associated collection id) then the rarely used "all" which must travel over every item in memory. I think the throw away struct leading to a struct might be the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your answer, you got me confused for a bit. I guess I had been overthinking your question.

I understand now that the only thing you needed was a struct implementing the `GetEnumerator()` method so you could do `foreach`, etc. I did not realize that you already had the `IEnumerator<>` implementations for the items themselves completed.

A possible improvement would be to have your `ItemEnumeratorWrapper` implement the full `IEnumerable` interface, so you can make it a private inner struct, as in:

```
private struct ItemEnumeratorWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : Item
{
    private ItemCollection _collection;

    public ItemEnumeratorWrapper<T>(ItemCollection collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }

    public ItemEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _collection.GetItemsOfTypeEnumerator<T>();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This allows you to return an `IEnumerable<T>` from your `ItemsOfType<T>()` method, and hides your implementation.

An alternative to the wrapper, is to have your `ItemEnumerator<T>` structs implement both the `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces, and also make them private. This would add only 2 very small additional methods to their implementation, and remove the need for an intermediate wrapper.

The example below is a bit contrived, because I don't know anything about the internals of your container(s), so I made a few things up to illustrate the idea.

```
private struct ItemEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T : Item
{
    // Specific types for your unsafe internals
    // completely made up.
    private readonly SomeTypeOfCollectionHandle _handle;
    private SomeTypeOfCursor _cursor = SomeTypeOfCursor.BeforeAll;

    public ItemEnumerator(SomeTypeOfCollectionHandle handle)
    { 
        _handle = handle;
    }

    // IEnumerable<T> implementation.
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // simply return a new instance with the same collection handle.
        return new ItemEnumerator(_handle);
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return (cursor = _handle.CursorNext(_cursor)).IsValid();
    }

    public T Current
    { 
        get
        {
            if (!_cursor.IsValid())
                throw new InvalidOperationException(); 
            return _cursor.Read<T>();
        }
    }

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return (object)((IEnumerator<T>)this).Current; }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cursor = _handle.CloseCursor(_cursor);
    }
}
```

Doing this would ensure that the public interface of `ItemCollection` exposes only standard BCL interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is a good example of where talking it out and taking a break works. The solution is indeed a throw away struct leading to a struct enumerator. I was following an atypical implementation that got me tangled up on the smell of a value type storing a value type enumerator and the potential for bad things to happen. Stepping back and starting fresh traditional class pattern can be easily adapted to structs without the smell.

```
public class ItemCollection
{
    private ItemEnumerator<T> GetItemsOfTypeEnumerator<T>() {}

    public ItemEnumeratorWrapper<T> ItemsOfType<T>()
    {
        return new ItemEnumeratorWrapper<T>(this);
    }

    public ItemEnumerator<Item> GetEmumerator() {}

    public struct ItemEnumeratorWrapper<T> where T : Item
    {
        private ItemCollection _collection;

        public ItemEnumeratorWrapper<T>(ItemCollection collection)
        {
            _collection = collection;
        }

        public ItemEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _collection.GetItemsOfTypeEnumerator<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Working with unsafe code and garbage collector management in .NET makes you start drastically overthinking things.